# How Can I join a String "" with a Value in VBA powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

So I have this textbox and a string I want to set a label to the string and the value combined like this:

```
Lebel1.Caption = "Hello" Textbox1.Text
```

I don't know what the proper code is.

Comment: `Lebel1.Caption ="Hello"  & Textbox1.Text`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are having a Typo issue. Not sure if your control is `Lebel` or `Label`.
In this example you can combine a predefined Text and a Control text or Variable. **Don't forget to add an space after your words.**

```
Label1.Caption = "Hello " & Textbox1.Text & "."
Label1.Caption = "Hello " & Your variable & "."
```

Also you can add a line break and also use a Message Box as follows:

```
Msgbox = "Welcome Message." & Chr(10) & "Hello " & Textbox1.Text & "."
```